# NameError: name 'Correct' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I am trying to check if the user typed in the correct password if they did then I want to make a bool true but for some reason it's just declaring a new bool with the same name **I have tried looking for other questions but none of them are in my situation**

````
Correct = False

def SubmitPassword():
        if e6.get() == password:
                Correct = True```
````

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need global variables? Also, for the given code, e6 and password are not defined, so please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

````
Correct = False

def SubmitPassword():
        global Correct
        if e6.get() == password:
                Correct = True```
````

try this code

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `not` operator for doing this.So in your case it will be something like `Correct= not Correct`